# ServiceNow encoded query syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, servicenow

I'm trying to write a query that includes encoded queries, but am not sure if my syntax is even correct (99.9% it's completely wrong).  I want this query to cycle through all of the available knowledge articles and based on the job series and location, provide the user with the correct article.  The first step is to grab the job series and location of the user and save them as variables, which I've done here:

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('hr_profile');
    gr.addQuery('user', gs.getUserID());
    gr.query();
    if(gr.next())
    {
  var occ = gr.job_series.getHTMLValue();
  var loc = gr.user.location.getHTMLValue();
     }
```

Next, I want to match occ and loc to the series and location of the article.  There are a few rules I want included and it can be better explained by this visual:

[image]

Assuming my occ = 2210 and my loc = Rockville, MD, I would be served with article #5 (blue).  If my occ is 2210, but I'm located in San Francisco, CA, I want to be served article #4, because job series takes priority over location.  If my occ is 1234 and I'm located in Rockville, I would be served with article #1 since my job series is absent.  Finally, in the off chance my occ is 0101 and my location is in Portland, OR (both not on this list), I would be served with article #7.  With this, I started coding the below query, but it doesn't work.

I'm pretty sure the syntax is wrong especially dealing with the encoded portion of the code.  Can someone help me troubleshoot?

```
var ka = new GlideRecord('x_knowledge_articles');
   ka.addQuery('workflow_state', 'published');
   ka.query();
   while(ka.next()) {
       if("seriesLIKE"+occ+"^locationLIKE"+loc) {
            data.article = ka.number.getHTMLValue(); }
       else if("seriesLIKE"+occ+"^locationNOT LIKE"+loc) {
            var occDefault = "seriesLIKE"+occ+"^locationISEMPTY"
            data.article = occDefault.number.getHTMLValue(); }
      else if("locationLIKE"+loc+"^seriesNOT LIKE"+occ) {
            var locDefault = "locationLIKE"+loc+"^seriesISEMPTY"
            data.article = locDefault.number.getHTMLValue();}
       else {
            data.article = 'KB0010050';
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you're using IF statements when an extension of your GlideRecord would be more effective. We will also leverage the `'CONTAINS'` [operator of addQuery](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Using_GlideRecord_to_Query_Tables#Available_JavaScript_Operators), which serves as a LIKE statement. If the `occ` and `loc` variables actually are HTML fields, we'll need to use `'CONTAINS'`, but we need to use the more exact `'='` (aka the default operation) if the value is blank.

Try out the code below, OP:

```
// To the best of my knowledge, the hr_profile code is fine
var gr = new GlideRecord('hr_profile');
gr.addQuery('user', gs.getUserID());
gr.query();
if(gr.next())
{
    var occ = gr.job_series.getHTMLValue();
    var loc = gr.user.location.getHTMLValue();
}


var ka = new GlideRecord('x_knowledge_articles');
ka.addQuery('workflow_state', 'published');

// We'll want to take blank values into account
// because using a CONTAINS addQuery on blank would return everything
if(occ == ''){
    // The line below is no different from ka.addQuery('series', occ)
    ka.addQuery('series', '=', occ);
}
else{
    ka.addQuery('series', 'CONTAINS', occ);
}

if(loc == ''){
    ka.addQuery('location', '=', loc);
}
else{
    ka.addQuery('location', 'CONTAINS', loc);
}       
ka.query();

if(ka.hasNext()){
    // I don't know if you need .getHTMLValue() for a number. Have you tried a vanilla getValue()?
    data.article = ka.number.getValue();
}
// If the queries above fail, fall back on KB0010050
else{
    data.article = 'KB0010050';
}
```

Comment: ...and you're going to need a call to `ka.next()` to actually move to the data in the queried GlideRecord so that the call to `ka.number` has data at the ready.